# How to get the path to the currently running Java command-line path? (before symbolic links)

Tags: java, command-line

I've written a program that outputs a usage hint. It currently echos back the path to the main `jar` file as was originally entered on the command line.

```
Usage: java -jar path/to/MyJar.jar <params> ...
```

For completeness, I'd like to make sure that the `java` bit is echoed back as well, as there are various ways to access `java`, (beyond just the word `java`, and **shorter than the canonical path** to `/us/opt/java-1.8.0-u123/bin/java`)

```
Usage: /us/opt/java7/bin/java -jar MyJar.jar <params> ...
Usage: ./bin/java -jar MyJar.jar <params> ...
Usage: java -jar MyJar.jar <params> ...
# whatever the user typed in
```

How can I determine what command-line was used to evoke the JVM?
I would like the original command-line value, prior to evaluating symbolic links.

I'm not using `System.getProperty("java.home")` because it has no respect for the original command-line value, just the final 'canonical' location of the JVM. (Having a usage note like `Usage: /us/opt/java-1.8.0-u123/jre/bin/java -jar ...` would be rather verbose,
especially when using simple `java` on the command line.)

Is determining the command-line location of `java` possible using pure Java code?
(i.e. not using a wrapper script in `bash`)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determining location of JVM executable during runtime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3392416/determining-location-of-jvm-executable-during-runtime)

Comment: I wonder why the downvote. Is it because the question is unclear or because it is duplicate? I did search before asking but I kept getting results that did not solve this particular question.

Comment: It's not immediately clear that you were aware of the other options, or what you're trying to do that you can't do with the top-voted answer in the linked question.

Comment: Well, I was not aware of the linked question. Now that I've looked, I'll edit my question to clarify.

Comment: How about http://stackoverflow.com/a/12989117/113632 ?

Comment: @dimo414, Gosh, that's pretty helpful. `getProperty("sun.java.command")` is a much simpler way to get the path to `MyJar.jar`, compared to what I was doing, even if it isn't completely cross-platform. However this is not the path to the `java` executable. If I could get that answer I'd be all set. :-)

Comment: `sun.java.command` will only work with Oracle JVM

Comment: @11thdimension, Understood. I'm going to use my existing code as a fallback in case `sun.java.command` is not set.

Answer (score 1):

Use following command

```
jps -mlvV
```

This should print everything about running java processes.

Where as `ps -e` should give you executable path.

Following is pure Java solution, it doesn't print the actual command used to execute the application but it produces a command which will have the same effect.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Printing command");
        createCommand();
    }
    public static void createCommand() {
        try {
            String jvm = getJvmExecutable();
            String mainClassName = findMainClass();
            String processDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");


            String arguments = getArguments();
            String classpath = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getClassPath();


            String command = String.format("cd %s & %s %s -classpath %s %s",processDir, jvm, arguments, classpath, mainClassName);

            System.out.println(command);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static String getJvmExecutable() {
        String jvm = "";
        jvm = System.getProperty("java.home");
        jvm += File.separator + "bin" + File.separator + "java";
        jvm = '"' + jvm + '"';
        return jvm;
    }

    private static String getArguments() {
        List<String> argsList = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getInputArguments();
        String args = argsList.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(" "));

        return args;
    }

    public static String findMainClass() throws ClassNotFoundException{
        for (Entry<Thread, StackTraceElement[]> entry : Thread.getAllStackTraces().entrySet()) {
            Thread thread = entry.getKey();
            if (thread.getThreadGroup() != null && thread.getThreadGroup().getName().equals("main")) {
                for (StackTraceElement stackTraceElement : entry.getValue()) {
                    if (stackTraceElement.getMethodName().equals("main")) {

                        try {
                            Class<?> c = Class.forName(stackTraceElement.getClassName());
                            Class[] argTypes = new Class[] { String[].class };
                            //This will throw NoSuchMethodException in case of fake main methods
                            c.getDeclaredMethod("main", argTypes);
                            return stackTraceElement.getClassName();
                        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Note:** It will work with plain java projects or normal JARS, however it will not work with special classloading like WAR, OSGI or Spring Boot's classloading.

I used the `findMainClass()` method from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/8275751/5343269

Comment: I'm looking for a pure Java code solution, so the application can generate its own usage script. It seems inefficient to `exec` an external process such as `jps` or `ps` for this purpose.

Comment: I clarified the question. I already have the path to main class, and to my jar, but what I am looking for is a path to java, which is not so terse. So if the user types `java` then the usage note can just be `java`. If the user typed a symbolic link, I just want that. I do *not* want to *always* show the 'full path' as would be returned by `System.getProperty("java.home")`.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand it correctly, there can be multiple version of Java installed on the machine, that's why I have used the `java.home` to retrieve the JVM which was used to launch the process.

Comment: I'm not actually trying to get the 'absolute' and 'canonical' path of the JVM. I want what the user typed in, which could be just the word `java`, or a relative path `./mydir/bin/java`, absolute path to symlink `/usr/bin/java` or full canonical path. I do not want to always reflect the full canonical path back, I want to reflect back what was typed.

Answer (score 0):

Use this System property in code

```
System.getProperty("java.home");
```

This will return Installation directory for Java Runtime Environment (JRE)

More info [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html)

Comment: I've clarified the question. This answer doesn't work for me.